# como podria saber si este Web Service Rest cliente funcionando?

Tags: webservice, restful

estoy tratando de saber si este web servicer esta funcionado esta en Rest me lo enviaron para poder realizar pruebas pero no se si puede ser mi pc o el servicio que no esta funcionando correstamente

adjunto el link web service Rest
http://172.18.131.195:9090/lince/rest/pazysalvo1/avaldescfin

```html
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array("entidad" => "F001",
          "tipoIdentificacion" => "CC",
          "numeroIdentificacion" => "1098623345"
);
    

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    ));


$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://172.18.131.195:9090/lince/rest/pazysalvo1/avaldescfin', false, $context),true);
print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Teclea <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> y escribe `CMD`

Luego escribe `ping` y la IP. Deberías obtener algo como esto:

El resultado dice que el sitio no está disponible, no recibe paquete de datos

> C:\Users\odrag> ping 172.18.131.195
>
> Haciendo ping a 172.18.131.195 con 32 bytes de datos:
>
> Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
>
> Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
>
> Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
>
> Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
>
> Estadísticas de ping para 172.18.131.195:
>
> Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 0, perdidos = 4 (100% perdidos)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda, osea que algo debe estar mal en el codigo ya que no envia los datos, pero es raro por que cuando envio los datos me responde.